# Angular2: Trying to diff '[object Object]' while calling values back from db

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript

I am trying to filter the values of my select named branches on the basis of another select named company but when I try to update the value of branches array I get the error:

> Trying to diff [object Object]

My service:

```
getCCBs() {
    return this._http.get('CustomerCompanyBranches/GetCCBs').map(res => res.json());
}
```

My Component:

```
export class CompanyComponent {

companies: CustomerCompany[];
branches: any;

constructor(private _ser: DemoService) {}

getComps() {
    this._ser.getCCs().subscribe(res => this.companies = res);
}
getCBran() {
    this._ser.getCCBs().subscribe(res => this.branches = res);
}

onSelect(customercompanyname) {
    console.log(customercompanyname);
    this.branches = this._ser.getCCBs().subscribe(res => res.find(br => br.CustomerCompanyBranchName === customercompanyname));
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.getComps();
    this.getCBran();
}
```

}

My html:

```
<label>Company:</label>
<select (change)="onSelect(t.value)" #t>
    <option value="0">--Select--</option>
    <option *ngFor="#c of companies" value={{c.CustomerCompanyName}}>{{c.CustomerCompanyName}}</option>
</select>
{{t.value}}
<br /><br />
<div >
    <label>Branch:</label>
    <select>
        <option *ngFor="#b of branches">
        {{b.CustomerCompanyBranchAddress}}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to make your assignment in the subscribe function.

```
onSelect(customercompanyname) {
        console.log(customercompanyname);
        this._ser.getCCBs().subscribe(res => res.find(br => { this.branches =  = br.CustomerCompanyBranchName === customercompanyname } ));
    }
```

Comment: It says "Error trying to diff the value coming from db "... What should I do now?